# How to apply array methods on string array in IBM conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

In IBM Conversation, if we make a context variable array that contains other arrays (like entities) then it becomes a string array. As per the documentation, you cannot perform array methods like `size()` or `length()` on string arrays. Any way to perform such functions on string array?

Comment: I have some examples here https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/watson-conversation-variables Also, could you add an example to you are having issues with?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between array and string type in Watson Conversation Service. To get the information about size of an array - that is to get the information about the number of elements contained by the array type one can use the `size()` method.

For type string to get the information about the number of characters in a string one can use `length()` method.

Here is an example of both. The string looks like an array but it is a string (enclosed by quotes `""`. Notice the array type lacking the quotes around it:

```
{
  "context": {
    "my_string" : "[\"one\", \"two\", \"three\"]",
    "my_array": [
      "one",
      "two",
      "three"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "This is string size: <?$my_string.length()?>. This is my array size: <? context.my_array.size()?>"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the answer from the dialog: 
`This is string size: 23. This is my array size: 3`

Function `length()` is supported on string types.
Function `size()` is supported on array types.

Comment: This is a link to WCS doc of the `size()` method: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-methods.html#methods-to-process-values

Comment: Hi Michal, My query is actually related to "string arrays" which are arrays containing arrays as defined in Conversation doc. Ill further explain: If array is : "$array : ["one","two"]

Then --> $string_array : "string array: [\"one\",\"two\"]"

You can subsequently perform array methods on the $array variable, such as <? $array.removeValue('two') ?> but not the $string_array variable."

Comment: Ah I see. I was confused by the word array in the name. :) So `string_array` is inf fact of string type... I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the example in the documentation might be confusing you.

You can nest arrays, even string arrays, and still manipulate them as array data types. The intention of the example you reference in the documentation was to show that if you include an array context variable in a dialog response as part of a string, the array is treated as a string data type.

For example, you can specify this in the JSON editor for a dialog node:

```
{
    "context": {
        "array": [
            "one",
            "two"
        ],
        "array_of_strings": [
            "<? $array ?>",
            "three",
            "four"
        ],
        "string_array": "this is an array: $array"
    },
```

When you execute the node in the "Try it out" panel, and then check the context variable values, they look like this:

```
$array
["one","two"]

$array_of_strings
[["one","two"],"three","four"]

$string_array
"this is an array: [\"one\",\"two\"]"
```

Note: I was able to include the first array as an array data type in my `$array_of_strings` context variable. It is not until I include the array in a string that it acts like a string. I hope that makes sense?